# jQuery outbound link anonymisation + legal notice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

How would I have a jQuery (preferably) script iterate through every single `<a>` tag and find any that don't start with

```
http://www.example.com/
```

and change the src attribute to

```
http://www.example.com/outbound/?verifyAge=0&dest='+encodeURIComponent(original_src)
```

and also apply `rel="external" target="_blank"`?

Comment: Have you tried any approach to this yet?  For starters, your jQuery selector would just be `'a'`.  So you'd start with something like: `$('a').each(function() { ... });`  Within that function you'd modify the attributes on `this` (the `href` attribute would be conditionally modified, the new attributes would be added, etc.).

Comment: I tried 'a' but it seems .. really inefficient.. was wondering if there was a "better" way, like `!'a[href=http://www.example.com]'` or something equally dumb like that that I'm sure isn't valid

Comment: That's actually pretty close to what you want. Look up the attribute does not equal value selector. http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/PXPxt/)'s a quick proof of concept:

HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
<a href="test.html">Test</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('a').not('[href^="http"]').each(function () {
    var element = $(this);
    element.attr('href', element.attr('href') + '?foo=baz');
    element.attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

Essentially what the JavaScript is doing is finding any `a` element which **doesn't begin with** `http` (you'll want to [expand that conditional logic](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) for your own needs, as well as handle any issues with having to escape the slashes in the URL or anything like that), grabs a reference to it as a jQuery object (I don't remember if `this` is already a jQuery object, if it is you can omit that part), modifies its `href` attribute and adds a `target` attribute.

Comment: Very much appreciated, I've used jQ before but haven't really got into the whole chaining different things together. Thanks

Comment: @jmoon: Naturally, you'll want to wrap this in a `$(document).ready()` or use `.on()`, etc. to make sure that the selector doesn't miss elements by looking before they've been loaded into the DOM.

Comment: Yeah, will be wrapped in a ready. For anyone that stumbles upon this from a google result or something/sake of completeness, `href=^="http:\/\/www.example.com"` appears to work for escaping slashes

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this would work.

```
​$('a')
    .filter( function() { return $(this).attr('href').indexOf('www.example.com') !== 0; })
    .each( function(i, el) {
        var curHref = el.attr('href');
        el.attr('rel', 'external');
        el.attr('target', '_blank');            
        el.attr('href', 'http://www.example.com/outbound/verifyAge=0&dest='+encodeURIComponent(curHref));             
    }​);
```

​There is a plug-in to do regex matching on elements, but using a regex for this seems like overkill to me.